# Go "unexpected end of JSON input" error

Tags: go

I know this has been asked a few times, but I don't see one that matches my need to support NULL values. I have fields that are optional in a DB. I need to output data in JSON format that includes these potentially NULL fields, which I would like to omit from the JSON if they are still NULL. I can change to some other default value other than NULL, but I haven't found one that works. I'm storing JSON arrays in JSON format (longtext) in MariaDB. Here's my code that fails (Playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/hLRh0d5D_CA)):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var respBytes = []byte("")
// Example data [12345, 23456, 34567]

func main() {
    var jsonData []interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(respBytes, &jsonData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(jsonData)
}
```

Replace `respBytes` empty string with example data and it works. Example data is simple JSON number array such as: "[12345, 23456, 34567]". How can I get it to work with data and without?

Comment: What do you want to happen when there's no data? Can you just check if there's data before you decode it?

Comment: I have several of these fields to check, so I was hoping for something more elegant, but that's my fall back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get it to work with data and without?

Unfortunately, you can't, with the standard library `json` package. It validates the JSON input before (while) decoding it, and an empty string is not valid JSON, so it will err before you even have a chance to decode with a custom unmarshaler.

In this particular case, the only real option is to check for valid input first.  Of course, you can do this with a wrapping function if you want:

```
func myUnmarshal(input []byte, target interface{}) error {
    if len(input) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(input, target)
}
```